# add the same code in multiple methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have a class that has N methods.

```
class MyClass
  def self.method_one(params)
    #specific code
  end

  def self.method_two(params)
    #specific code
  end
end
```

I need to add the same code for each method created in that class. I need to put the code between "*begin and rescue*"

I tried the following, but I did not succeed:

```
class MyClass < BaseClass
  add_rescue :method_one, :method_two, Exception do |message|
    raise message                                                     
  end

  def self.method_one(params)
    #specific code
  end

  def self.method_two(params)
    #specific code
  end
end
```

I created a method to change the methods

```
class BaseClass
  def self.add_rescue(*meths, exception, &handler)
    meths.each do |meth|
      old = instance_method(meth)
      define_method(meth) do |*args|
        begin
          old.bind(self).call(*args)
        rescue exception => e
          handler.call(e)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I always get the error message: ***undefined method `method_one 'for Myclass: Class***

Comment: _Sidenote:_ even if this worked, you discard the block that might be passed to the method in your wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyClass#method_one` is a class method or, in other words, the instance method of `MyClass.singleton_class`. That said, we can [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) the desired functionality to `MyClass.singleton_class`:

```
def self.add_rescue(*meths, exception, &handler)
  mod =
    Module.new do
      meths.each do |meth|
        define_method meth do |*args, &λ|
          begin
            super(*args, &λ)
          rescue exception => e
            handler.(e) 
          end
        end
      end
    end

  MyClass.singleton_class.prepend(mod)
end
```